# Exclude pod depends on platform in podfile

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec, podfile

I need to exclude a pod from my `podfile` depends on the platform. I don't want to add another target, my `podfile` needs have only 1 target.

Here an example:

```
target 'single_target' do
    #if platform is iOS
    pod 'PodForIOS'
    #if platform is OSX
    pod 'PodForOSX'
end
```

**My issue:** How can I specify which pods belongs to which platform ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly I've found a **solution**

In the `podfile`:

```
target 'single_target' do
    pod 'PodForIOS'
    pod 'PodForOSX'
end
```

In the `.podspec`:

```
# Speficy platforms
s.platform = :ios, :osx
s.ios.deployment_target = '6.0'
s.osx.deployment_target = '10.8'

# Set dependency
s.ios.dependency 'PodForIOS'
s.osx.dependency 'PodForOSX'
```

Answer (score 0):

A target in a Podfile refers to a target in an .xcproject. And those are strictly tied to a specific plateform:
[image: Choose a template for your new target]

So you should go with one abstract target (in Podfile) and multiple targets (in Project).

Comment: As I said, I don't want to add target in my project. Thank you anyway

Comment: I know. Just mentioning that a target can only be for one platform, so your request is impossible and the requirement is unjustified.

Comment: Yes, thank you for you answer ! It'll help me in the futur :)
It's justify. I have a pod which is multi-platform, but in this pod, i call other pods which are for `ios` and `osx` target, this pod can be used by `ios` and `osx` projects... So I just need to make this pod usable by both

Comment: Please add those details in your question. :)

Comment: I thaught it was useless to explain, and just want to explain what want I do :)